# Why won't the red header background appear?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the Vintage template http://www.html5xcss3.com/2012/07/html5-template-vintage-responsive.html

I have implemented it at http://romeavenue.com

However, I can't get the red background to appear in the header behind the logo and have no idea why it's not working.  Anyone any ideas??

thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

The `div` with the logo and the `nav` are inside a `header` element on the theme. But not on your site.

This `header` element has the red background image.